# MySQL - Does a SELECT command on a specific column causing a local snapshot in a transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions

Greetings to everyone,

Recently I tried the scenario issued below and I want your opinion on this.
Using MySQL/INNODB, on a table t (a,b,c,d) values (10,20,30,40) we have these two transactions (A and B) executing in the order specified below:

1) A,B: set autocommit=0;

2)B: set transaction isolation level repeatable read;

3)B: select d from t;

4)A: update t set a=a+3;

5)A: commit;

6)B select * from t;

The values returned from (6) are (10,20,30,40) as if the selection of column d on (3) caused a local snapshot to be created on transaction B and since B has repeatable read it keeps consistent values. Is this true, or is there another explanation for this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySQL seems to automatically start a transaction in this case:

> Suppose that you are running in the default REPEATABLE READ isolation
>   level. When you issue a consistent read (that is, an ordinary SELECT
>   statement), InnoDB gives your transaction a timepoint according to
>   which your query sees the database.
>
> […]
>
> You can advance your timepoint
>   by committing your transaction and then doing another SELECT or START
>   TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-consistent-read.html

Especially the last sentence sounds like the next `SELECT` will automatically create a new transaction. (And it also states what to do to do move on: `commit` or `rollback`, but I guess you already knew that.)

Comment: Thank you for your post it was really helpful! Although my original question was if reading a single column of a table is causing a timepoint to be created for the whole table and all of its contents. Basically I'm asking if selecting a column from a table creates a timepoint on table level and not column level

Comment: Actually I read it as a database wide snapshot, see the same link: `The query sees the changes made by transactions that committed before that point of time, and no changes made by later or uncommitted transactions.`, but there are some special cases, which are all listed on the linked page. Maybe you should read through it.

Comment: Thank you for your time!